# System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: 'A generic error occurred in GDI+.' in printing a file via C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I made a billing software for a temple in Kerala for printing the rcpt for the devotees who gave offerings to the temple. When print button is clicked, the printer must print the rcpt details to a form. I made a print button and a print document  and coded the document like this:

```
private void RCPT_PRINTABLE_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString(RCPTNO.Text, new Font("ML-NILA02_NewLipi", 15, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new Point(94 , 109));
    e.Graphics.DrawString(RcptDate.Text, new Font("ML-NILA02_NewLipi", 15, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(408, 109));
    e.Graphics.DrawString(NameRcpt.Text, new Font("Times New Roman", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(94, 132));
    e.Graphics.DrawString(RCPTSTAR.Text, new Font("ML-NILA02_NewLipi", 15, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(408, 132));



    //DATEBOOKING PRINT BEGIN   
    if (Vazhipaad1.Text != "--")
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("1. "+Vazhipaad1.Text + "(" + dateTimePicker2.Text + ")"+ "(" + No1.Text + "*" + Rate1.Text + ")", new Font("ML-NILA02_NewLipi", 15, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(57, 200) );
        e.Graphics.DrawString("₹" + textBox1.Text, new Font("ML-NILA02_NewLipi", 15, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(434, 200));
    }


    if (Vazhipaad2.Text != "--")
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("2. "+Vazhipaad2.Text + "(" + dateTimePicker1.Text + ")" + "(" + No2.Text + "*" + Rate2.Text + ")", new Font("ML-NILA02_NewLipi", 15, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(57, 234));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("₹" + textBox2.Text, new Font("ML-NILA02_NewLipi", 15, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(434, 234));
    }

    if (Vazhipaad3.Text != "--")
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("3. "+Vazhipaad3.Text + "(" + dateTimePicker5.Text + ")" + "(" + No3.Text + "*" + Rate3.Text + ")", new Font("ML-NILA02_NewLipi", 15, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(57, 265));
        e.Graphics.DrawString("₹" + textBox3.Text, new Font("ML-NILA02_NewLipi", 15, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(434, 265));
    }


    e.Graphics.DrawString("₹" + TOTAL.Text, new Font("ML-NILA02_NewLipi", 20, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, new Point(397, 302));

    e.Graphics.Dispose();

}
```

But when this code is executed, within the second if statement, 1st line an exeption **System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: 'A generic error occurred in GDI+.'**
 is thrown by the system. I refered lot and lot websites but didn't find perfect answers. Please help me!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I suggest to prepare the strings you want to print and print them in a 2nd statement. This way you can see if the strings get created right and which line throws..

Comment: Remove this **e.Graphics.Dispose();** and try.